# How to make UITextField move up when keyboard present without using scroll View and not move in constant value?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, keyboard, textfield

my needs:

1. to move the UIView up base on whether textField covered by keyboard and how much it covered.
2. Don't want to use scrollView to rebuild it.

to achieve 1. I have to know the coordinate Y of the textField I chose. Lots of
answers using NSNotificationCenter to build a listener. There is what i don't understand, why set nil to object? isn't the object who trigger the function below? I try to get the position of the object but failed. Because I set the nil to object. try to set textField to object still not working.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: UITextField())

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: UITextField())
```

How to get the position of the chosen textField? if not declare something like this:

```
@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!
```

Is there hidden information inside notification? maybe in the userInfo? cause the keyboard's height is in it.

```
let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
```

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class VC_Base: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{

    var keyBoardShow:Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(VC_Base.keyboardWillShow), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: self)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(VC_Base.keyboardWillHide), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: self)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        guard keyBoardShow else{
            adjustingHightLight(true, notification: notification)
            keyBoardShow = true
            return
        }
        keyBoardShow = true
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        adjustingHightLight(false, notification: notification)
        keyBoardShow = false
    }

    func adjustingHightLight(show: Bool, notification: NSNotification) {
        var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
        if let object = notification.object as! UITextField!{
            print("there is object")
            let textFieldCoverByKeyBoard = self.view.frame.maxY - object.frame.maxY
            let keyboardFrame: CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
            let differenceOfTextFieldAndKeyBoard = textFieldCoverByKeyBoard - keyboardFrame.height
            let animationDuration = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSTimeInterval
            let changeInHeight = differenceOfTextFieldAndKeyBoard * (show ? 1 : -1)
            if differenceOfTextFieldAndKeyBoard < 5{
                UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.view.frame.offsetInPlace(dx: 0, dy: changeInHeight)}, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return true
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
}
```

texting is the basic function it should achieve several things below:

1.whether the keyboard cover textField?

if true, how much did it cover and move the UIView upward the value so the keyboard won't cover it.
  if false, do nothing and show keyboard.

2.if I already select one textField and then chose another. it won't move up again (which will happened in some answers).

But seems there are not much answer fulfill it except using scrollView(which I don't want to rebuild...)

please help!!THX.